# How could you create an SSX style snow trail in unity3d?

Tags: unity

So it SSX (a snowboarding game) when you are snowboarding you leave behind a dents in the snow(like a trail) .It's like how if you take a step in the snow you will leave a footprint behind but with a snowboard you leave a trail of where your snowboard has been. Can you create this or is this not supported by unity? If you can, how? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Trail or line renderer: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html. Just have a darker texture to overlay the snow and continuously set a new position for the trail renderer.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably learn more about [decals](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-NormalDecal.html) and take a look at [this forum post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/simple-skidmark-setup-for-your-unity-racing-game.168261/). It looks like what you are trying to achieve.
I hope it helps.